# Determine whether T: $ R^3 \to R^2 $ defined as $T(x,y,z) = (x, x+y+z)$ is a linear transformation under euclidean operations in $R^3 $and $R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a little unsure how to start this I know i have to prove $T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v)$. Here is what I have tried so far: Let $ u=(u_1,u_2,u_2), v=(v_1,v_2,v_3), w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)  \\ T(u+v) = T(u_1 + v_1 + w_1, u_2 + v_2 + w_2, u_3 + v_3 + w_3) \\ T(u+v) = ((u_1), (u_2 + v_2 + w_3) \\ = T(u) + T(v) $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T(u+v) = T(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2,u_3+v_3)=(u_1+v_1,\sum u+\sum v) = (u_1,\sum u)+(v_1,\sum v) = T(u) + T(v)$. Also $T(ru) = rT(u), r$ is a scalar. Thus $T$ is indeed a L.T.